# How can I make every capital letter use a 'stylistic alternate'?

Tags: adobe-indesign

The 'stylistic set' included with this font "Historycal" is only for small caps, but I need to be able to make a GREP, paragraph style, or character style that will effect every capital.

I know this is possible because somehow previous versions of my document have this. There are just way too many instances in my book to do this manually.